# Why does this HtmlAgilityPack code stop working when I dig deeper via XPath?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, xpath, html-agility-pack

This code runs properly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Dynamic;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace entropedizer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public String postRequest(string url, string eventTarget)
        {
            // A "pre-request," sent to gather SessionID and POST data parameters for the main request
            HttpWebRequest prequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart");
            HttpWebResponse presponse = (HttpWebResponse)prequest.GetResponse();
            Stream pstream = presponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader psr = new StreamReader(pstream);
            string phtml = psr.ReadToEnd();

            Match viewstate = Regex.Match(phtml, "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\".+/>");
            Match eventvalidation = Regex.Match(phtml, "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\".+/>");
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "__EVENTTARGET=" + eventTarget + "&__VIEWSTATE=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(viewstate.ToString().Substring(24, viewstate.Length - 28)) + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(eventvalidation.ToString().Substring(30, eventvalidation.Length - 34));
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            // The main request, intended to retreive the desired HTML
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            Cookie sessionId = new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", Regex.Match(presponse.Headers.ToString(), "ASP.NET_SessionId=.+ d").ToString().Substring(18, Regex.Match(presponse.Headers.ToString(), "ASP.NET_SessionId=.+ d").Length - 21), "/", ".entropedia.info");
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart"), sessionId);

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hChart = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            hChart.LoadHtml(postRequest("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart", "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24DG1%24ctl19%24ctl05"));

            HtmlNodeCollection chartStrings = hChart.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/form");

            CheckedListBox chartOptions = new CheckedListBox();
            foreach (HtmlNode i in chartStrings)
            {
                chartOptions.Items.Add(chartStrings[i].ToString());
            }
            this.Controls.Add(chartOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

This code generates a run-time exception:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Dynamic;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace entropedizer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public String postRequest(string url, string eventTarget)
        {
            // A "pre-request," sent to gather SessionID and POST data parameters for the main request
            HttpWebRequest prequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart");
            HttpWebResponse presponse = (HttpWebResponse)prequest.GetResponse();
            Stream pstream = presponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader psr = new StreamReader(pstream);
            string phtml = psr.ReadToEnd();

            Match viewstate = Regex.Match(phtml, "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\".+/>");
            Match eventvalidation = Regex.Match(phtml, "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\".+/>");
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "__EVENTTARGET=" + eventTarget + "&__VIEWSTATE=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(viewstate.ToString().Substring(24, viewstate.Length - 28)) + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(eventvalidation.ToString().Substring(30, eventvalidation.Length - 34));
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            // The main request, intended to retreive the desired HTML
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            Cookie sessionId = new Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", Regex.Match(presponse.Headers.ToString(), "ASP.NET_SessionId=.+ d").ToString().Substring(18, Regex.Match(presponse.Headers.ToString(), "ASP.NET_SessionId=.+ d").Length - 21), "/", ".entropedia.info");
            request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart"), sessionId);

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hChart = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            hChart.LoadHtml(postRequest("http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart", "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24DG1%24ctl19%24ctl05"));

            HtmlNodeCollection chartStrings = hChart.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/form/table");

            CheckedListBox chartOptions = new CheckedListBox();
            foreach (HtmlNode i in chartStrings)
            {
                chartOptions.Items.Add(chartStrings[i].ToString());
            }
            this.Controls.Add(chartOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is line 68.  I simply attempted to dig one layer deeper into the HTML, which causes chartStrings to be null.

This is the exception:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at entropedizer.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\entropedizer\entropedizer\Form1.cs:line 71
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
entropedizer
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/entropedizer/entropedizer/bin/Debug/entropedizer.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18036 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18021 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
HtmlAgilityPack
    Assembly Version: 1.4.6.0
    Win32 Version: 1.4.6.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/entropedizer/entropedizer/bin/Debug/HtmlAgilityPack.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Thanks in advance for any help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Html Agility Pack's SelectSingleNode and SelectNodes methods return null instead of an empty collection (I know it's stupid and very uncommon). So, you're select calls probably return nothing.

Comment: Indeed, I am wondering why my first example returns null and not the second.  I cannot seem to paste the html in hStrings (too large to post, and pastebins (at least ideone) don't seem to work easily on this site.  The html can be seen though by visiting http://www.entropedia.info/Chart.aspx?chart=Chart and clicking the "(All)" link under the chart, then viewing the page source.